# Uncaught TypeError that blocks all other functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, typeerror, uncaught-reference-error

I keep getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' error on my console when running my code. All other functions are working without any issue. It seems to be related to a single event listener. If I remove the code block the rest of my functions run perfectly. I have tried moving my script tags around but cant seem to fix it..

```
    .JS
    // sign-up a new user
const signupForm = document.querySelector("#signup-form");
signupForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

 
  // get user info
  const email = signupForm["login-email"].value;
  const password = signupForm["login-password"].value;

  // Check email address
  if (!email.includes("@companyName.ac.uk")) {
    console.log("invalid email address");
    window.location.replace("404.html");
  } else {
    // sign up user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((cred) => {
      const loader = document.querySelector(".formPro");
      loader.style.display = "block";

      // Load animation + close modal
      setTimeout(() => {
        const modal = document.querySelector("#modal-signup");
        M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
        signupForm.reset();
        loader.style.display = "none";
        window.location.replace("eoi-tracker.html");
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
});

.HTML
<!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="auth.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try console logging `signupForm` before adding the eventListener. Your code may be running before the element is created

Comment: Just tried this and I get 'Cannot access 'signupForm' before initialization' returned. My script tags are already at the bottom of my page. Is the a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that function inside a page load event and you should be good to go. This will ensure that you only search for `signupForm` once the elements have been created on the page.

```
window.addEventListener("load", pageFullyLoaded, false);

function pageFullyLoaded(){
const signupForm = document.querySelector("#signup-form");
signupForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

 
  // get user info
  const email = signupForm["login-email"].value;
  const password = signupForm["login-password"].value;

  // Check email address
  if (!email.includes("@companyName.ac.uk")) {
    console.log("invalid email address");
    window.location.replace("404.html");
  } else {
    // sign up user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((cred) => {
      const loader = document.querySelector(".formPro");
      loader.style.display = "block";

      // Load animation + close modal
      setTimeout(() => {
        const modal = document.querySelector("#modal-signup");
        M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
        signupForm.reset();
        loader.style.display = "none";
        window.location.replace("eoi-tracker.html");
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
});
}
```

Comment: I am still getting this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'signupForm' before initialization
    at pageFullyLoaded (auth.js:3)
pageFullyLoaded @ auth.js:3
load (async)
(anonymous) @ auth.js:1

Comment: Do you have a variable `signupForm` declared anywhere else?